# Is broadcastreceiver considered a service?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I was digging this forum but couldn't find an answer to my questions ....

1, I developed SMS application by extending broadcastreceiver and everything is working great, the problem is that after the phone is sleeping for a while - the application is no longer working. So is broadcastreceiver considered a Service ? ( that will be killed by the Android after it's been idled for X minutes ).... because I don't have the "START_REDELIVER_INTENT" like I have inside a Service .... and I read some posts that said to use the AlarmManaget - but I don't understand why. ( the examples posts were not about receiving SMS though ... were in regards to calendars etc ... )

Bottom line - how do I fix this ? if I need to use a service to run itself after the android kills it - I don't understand how to convert my broadcastreceiver to be a service... ( because it's the only thing that needs to be running ... everything else is just settings and preferences ....)

2, When I install GOSMS for example, the android ask me - from now on which app would I like to work with as my default SMS program, what to I need to code in order to achieve this kind of notification to the end-users ?  right now my application only receive SMS notifications ... doesn't send anything ...

Thanks in advance....

Comment: To keep a service running & prevent the phone from sleeping while you're "doing your thing" you should keep a partial [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) that you *release* after you are done (unless you want users to start giving your app 1-star ratings).

Comment: Mmm... that's not what I meant. when the phone is asleep - it wakes up when I'm receiving SMS notification, my problem is that Android kills my process after X time

Comment: Ah, you're trying to do a "lot" of stuff in the receiver? That only works if it's actually registered in a running Service - not if its declared in the AndroidManifest.xml as a receiver - pass the contents of the Intent to a Service and do the work there (and hold a wake lock, because, srsly, the device may very well go back to sleep after it has delivered the Intent to your receiver).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it doesn't do a lot, it's a really simple thing: a Toast with my own template. And it's only declared in my AndroidManifest.xml. But as I understand, a service will also be killed after Xmin of no activity, correct ?

Answer (score 2):

> So is broadcastreceiver considered a Service ?

No, that's why it's called `BroadcastReceiver` and not `Service`.

Please see [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) to properly understand the various key components of an Android application.

Also, if you have correctly registered your `BroadcastReceiver's` `<intent-filter>` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` then it will be 'woken up' to process `Intents` although as Jens mentions that may require you acquiring a `WakeLock` of some sort (and correctly acquiring/handling/releasing various resources during/after your task is accomplished).